# Environment var (LD_LIBRARY_PATH) weirdly hidden under bash on Mac

Tags: terminal, bash, environment-variables

Here is a brief, self-explanatory bash session on Linux:

```
$ env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foo
$ env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foo
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
foo
```

Here is the same session on a Mac:

```
$ env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foo
$ env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
foo
```

Notice that, oddly, `env` does not include `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, even though it has been exported, and echo finds it. But it's not just an `env` thing. Other programs cannot find the environment variable. Here is a JVM (via the Scala REPL), after setting `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foo`:

```
scala> System.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
res0: String = null

scala> System.getenv("SHELL")
res1: String = /bin/bash
```

On Linux, `System.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")` yields the expected `foo`.

I'm trying to execute an external process from Scala that needs to inherit `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from the parent shell. But if the JVM can't see the parent shell's `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and doesn't inherit automatically, it's hard to get right.

On Linux everything works as expected.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you are using LD_LIBRARY_PATH on MacOS you probably have got something wrong. If on Sierra SIP stops you setting it. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212945/unable-to-set-dyld-fallback-library-path-in-shell-on-osx-10-11-1/212954#212954  macOS is not the same as Linux. So you need to read up on macOS shared librarioes and bundles.

Comment: @mark Please post this as an answer :-)

Comment: @patrix - in that case isn't this a dup of the answer I linked to? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212945/unable-to-set-dyld-fallback-library-path-in-shell-on-osx-10-11-1/212954#212954  I was wondering if there was a quick solution or do we have to look at the whole packaging oif the app?

Comment: @SteveWaldman - You need to provide details of the app you are executing - to see if it can be packaged in a mac way - or could you make it a library and call via JNI

Comment: @SteveWaldman If you are looking for ways to solve the problem of running an external process from Scala, please ask a new question about this specifically.